# Extracting values from Associations

Tags: associations

I have data stored in a list of Associations. I would like to extract the values only for multiple keys. I was hoping to do it the same way list[[All,{1,2}]] can be used. But when I use this syntax with Associations I extract Key-value pairs instead of values. Is their a terse syntax for what I want?

```
assoc = {
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6|>,
   <|"a" -> 7, "b" -> 8, "c" -> 9|>
   };

assoc[[All, "a"]]

(* {1,4,7} *)

assoc[[All, {"a", "b"}]]

{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> 5|>, <|"a" -> 7, 
  "b" -> 8|>}
```

Comment: `Is their a terse syntax for what I want?` I do not know. I do not  use associations much. But you could always use mapping I suppose: `assoc[[All, #]] & /@ {"a", "b"}`

Comment: `Lookup[{"a", "b"}] @ assoc`

Comment: Thanks, Nasser. I haven’t used them much myself. I find the syntax a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks also, Elmo. That works great.

Comment: @eldo, please post that as an answer. :) I didn't know `Lookup[]` can thread across a list of associations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Values[assoc[[All, {"a", "b"}]]]

{{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {7, 8}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s great.

Answer (score 7):

Upon request I post my comment as an answer.

The documentation states under examples:

> Lookup threads over lists of associations:

```
Lookup[{"a", "b"}] @ assoc
```

> {{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {7, 8}}