# Extracting values from association via Cases

Tags: pattern-matching

related: [Extracting values from Associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213517/extracting-values-from-associations)

I have an association of the form

`temp = <|"u" -> -5, "v" -> -5|> -> -30`

and want to extract the numerical values, after a bit of trying I found

`Cases[temp, _Integer, \[Infinity]]`

does the job. My first attempt was to rebuild the structure, like:

`Cases[temp, <|u -> x_, v -> y_|> -> z_ :> {x, y, z}]`

which does not work, due to the variables "u", "v", I assume. But also this does not work:

`Cases[temp, <|_ -> x_, _ -> y_|> -> z_ :> {x, y, z}]`

and I wonder why, the pattern should match. Can someone explain?

Comment: `Values@Keys@temp~Join~{Values@temp}`

Comment: `ReplaceAll[temp, HoldPattern[KeyValuePattern[{_ -> x_, _ -> y_}] -> z_] :> {x, y, z}]`.

Comment: @Syed Close to my first attempt: `{Values@Keys[temp], Values[temp]} // Flatten` ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the the Docs for `Cases`,

> The default value for *levelspec* in `Cases` is `{1}`.

You operate on the level `{0}`, so specify this level explicitly:

```
Cases[temp, HoldPattern[<|_ -> x_, _ -> y_|> -> z_] :> {x, y, z}, {0}]
```

> ```
> {{-5, -5, -30}}
> ```

You can also use `KeyValuePattern`:

```
Cases[temp, HoldPattern[KeyValuePattern[{_ -> x_, _ -> y_}] -> z_] :> {x, y, z}, {0}]
```

> ```
> {{-5, -5, -30}}
> ```

Alternatively, use `Replace` or `ReplaceAll`:

```
ReplaceAll[temp, HoldPattern[<|_ -> x_, _ -> y_|> -> z_] :> {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {-5, -5, -30}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer! I didn't had in mind `HoldPattern`....

Answer (score 2):

Let's say temp had a string value in there as well:

```
temp = <|"u" -> -5, "v" -> -5, "w" -> "a"|> -> -30
```

In order to select integers only:

```
Cases[temp, _Integer, {2}]~Join~Cases[temp, _Integer]
```

> {-5, -5, -30}